# I want to create a trigger to update a field in other table mydb.authors when a row is inserted in mydb.titles

Tags: mysql

I want to create a trigger to update a field in other table `mydb.authors` when a row is inserted in `mydb.titlesPlease` find my code below

```
create trigger mydb.t_count 
on mydb.titles
after insert 
as
declare @bcount int,@aid int(8);
select @bcount=count(*) from mydb.titles;
select @aid=author_id from mydb.titles;

if(@bcount>0)
begin
update table  mydb.authors set titles_count=@bcount where author_id=@aid;
end//
else
begin
insert into mydb.authors values(author_id,titles_count) values(@aid,@bcount);
end
delimiter;
```

Comment: What is your error? I assume, the end// has to be the last line before the delimeter;. and you have to deal with the [NEW-Object available in the insert trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). Also the query `select @aid=author_id from mydb.titles;` is selecting more then one entry, so the rest will fail. please provide table structure of mydb.titles, so maybe a primary key helps identifiying the right author_id.

Comment: Is it possible to pass argument to trigger....I want to update the titles_count filed in author table whenever a row is inserted in titles table how to keep track of primary key.... could you help me to resolve this

Comment: The only parameters to an after insert trigger is the NEW-Object containing all columns inserted/in the new row just inserted. Please provide the table structure of `mydb.titles` and `mydb.authors` by editing the question, then a help might be possible.

Comment: Titles table and its attributes are author_id,book_name. Then second table is authors and its attributes are auhtor_id, author_name and titles_count.  Thank you for replying me.

Comment: I need to first select the titles_count of a particular row from authors table by using new.author_id value in select command. Then I need to update the count by incrementing the value. Hope you understand.

Comment: create trigger mydb.t_count  after insert
on mydb.titles 
for each row 
update  mydb.authors set titles_count= 'titles_count'+1 where author_id=new.author_id;

Comment: create trigger mydb.t_count  after insert
on mydb.titles 
for each row 
update  mydb.authors set titles_count= 'titles_count'+1 where author_id=new.author_id;
I have created a trigger like this but when I am trying to insert a row in titles tables I am getting error stating    Truncated incorrect double value:titles_count..How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The correct trigger to your question:

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger mydb.t_count 
after insert 
on mydb.titles
for each row begin
declare l_aid BIGINT UNSIGNED;-- should fit the length of author_id

SET l_aid = NEW.author_id;

-- first checking, if there is already an entry in the authors table:
if EXISTS(SELECT author_id FROM mydb.authors WHERE author_id = l_aid) THEN
-- if yes then update
update mydb.authors set titles_count=titles_count + 1 where author_id=l_aid;
else -- else insert with counter 1.
insert into mydb.authors (author_id,titles_count) values(l_aid,1);
END IF;
end //
DELIMITER ;
```

### I've used the following table definition for this:

```
CREATE DATABASE `mydb` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
use `mydb`;


create table authors (
    author_id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    author_name VARCHAR(200),
    titles_count BIGINT
);

create table titles (
    title_id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    author_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    book_name vARCHAR(200),
    FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES authors(author_id)
);
```

Using only one Trigger may not fit, when you update or delete titles, the title count isn't updated yet.

### However, there is a solution without any trigger:

```
SELECT count(t.title_id) AS titles_count,t.author_id
FROM titles t
GROUP BY t.author.id;
```